# A skatterplot for two variables with two different colors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a scatterplot for two variables in R with ggplot:

```
ggplot(analizaDate, aes(stima, reusita)) +
  geom_point() + xlab('Stima de sine') + ylab('Reușita școlară') + labs(title="Diagrama împrăștierii") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

How to make these two variables in two different colors and how to add a legend for them?

My data:

```
analizaDate <- structure(list(Stima.de.sine = c(11, 17, 17, 17, 14, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 16, 14, 17, 17, 21, 17, 17, 17, 12, 17, 17, 17, 13, 
17, 16, 17, 12, 17, 19, 17, 17, 17, 17, 11, 17, 17, 17, 19, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 10, 17, 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 16, 11, 17, 
17, 14, 17, 19, 17, 17, 11, 17, 17, 15, 17, 17, 17, 18, 17, 17
), Reușita.școlară = c(45, 83, 89, 79, 37, 76, 57, 85, 82, 
66, 14, 43, 76, 53, 86, 73, 69, 90, 10, 116, 99, 78, 31, 72, 
39, 65, 9, 58, 89, 63, 79, 92, 109, 28, 91, 67, 74, 107, 76, 
90, 99, 88, 84, 104, 53, 61, 10, 84, 73, 89, 93, 75, 49, 41, 
64, 91, 45, 53, 109, 65, 101, 48, 85, 88, 46, 98, 75, 89, 72, 
61, 74)), .Names = c("Stima.de.sine", "Reușita.școlară"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-71L))
```

Comment: But on what basis do you want to separate the points. You should have some variable (some factor)

Comment: What color would your first point (11,45) be? I think you need to add a factor to color the points

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @TheRimalaya, the data lack of a basis to separate the points, such as a factor.  Anyway, if this could help you, I suggest you to use the Lattice package, which is particularly well suited for this kind of duties.
Please consider the following example.

The function `xyplot` plots two variables (`mpg` and `wt`) on the graph. The points on the plot are colored according a factor variable that you can use with the argument **groups**: it automatically colors the points for each level of our factor of choice (in this case, the variable `am)`.

```
library(lattice)
data(mtcars)
xyplot(mpg~wt,data=mtcars,groups=factor(am,labels=c("A","M")),
   pch=20,auto.key=list(columns=2),type=c("p","g"))
```

[image]